# $\mathsf{LLL}$ and linear diophantine equations

Tags: nt.number-theory, lattices, computational-number-theory

On page $8$ in these slides (http://www.math.unicaen.fr/~nitaj/LatticeMalaysia2014-2.pdf) it is told that if we want to solve $$x_1a_1+\dots+x_na_n=N$$ where $|x_i|<\frac{2^{n/4}N^\frac1{n+1}}{\sqrt n}$ holds then we have a polynomial time algorithm for this.

**(1)** What is the complexity of the algorithm? Is there a reference?

**(2)** Can we replace $|x_i|<\frac{2^{n/4}N^\frac1{n+1}}{\sqrt n}$ by $0\leq x_i<\frac{2^{n/4}N^\frac1{n+1}}{\sqrt n}$?

Comment: I don't understand your second question—it seems just like a weakening of what the slides already tell us.

Comment: @GregMartin why do you say $0\leq x_i<X$ is weaker than $|x_i|<X$? Each condition seems to give rise to a distinct problem.